# How to enable ASP.Net MVC item templates for S#arp Architecture project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, s#arp-architecture

I've been playing around with creating an application using the [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/).

One thing that is bugging me a bit is that I don't have access to any of the ASP.Net MVC item templates from the "Add New Item..." dialog. In other words I can't, for example, create a new "MVC ViewPage" or "MVC Controller" directly from the "Add New Item..." dialog.

As a result I have to create standard ASP.Net items, then manipulate the markup and code-behind to setup the correct inheritance structure.

**Is there any way to get the ASP.Net MVC item templates to work within the "Add New Item..." dialog of a project based on the S#arp Architecture project template?**

Comment: You should have a Visual C# -> Web -> MVC option in your Add New Item dialog.

Comment: You are right Todd. The thing is I had soft of ported the S#arp project template to VB.Net. I seem to have lost this ability in the translation. Gives me some place to start looking again though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to the comment from [Todd Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31624/todd-smith) in the original question.

The ASP.Net MVC item templates should be available in the "Add New Item..." dialog, under Web -> MVC.

What I neglected to mention in my original question (because I didn't think it was relevant) was that I had converted the original S#arp Architecture project template to VB.Net (being a bit more comfortable working in VB.Net these days). Turns out I lost the ability to access ASP.Net MVC templates during my conversion.

The fix was simple. My VB.Net version of the SharpArch.Web project wasn't identified as an MVC project. I simply had to add the appropriate project type GUID (i.e. **{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0}**) to the *.vbproj file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Thanks Todd!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531120/asp-net-mvc-project-not-supported-by-this-installation.

That first GUID always causes a cannot open this type of project error on load.