# ASP.NET MVC project "not supported by this installation"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I can create new MVC projects and they work and run however trying to open an existing project is not working at all.

I tried the following changing the project type to:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

(this worked on migrating a project from Asp.Net MVC preview 1 to preview 2 BTW)

Changed the Reference to:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>      
</Reference>
```

I tool this from a new project I created so i know that should be OK (I even hardcoded the path to the same result).

Still I get the dreaded:

> The project file '.....csproj' cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation.

I also tried `devenv /setup` and installing the SP1 for Visual Studio.

The project I'm trying to open is [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18206.aspx) one (a DevExpress sample of a grid working on ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Have you tried contacting DevExpress support?

Comment: no i haven't. I ll have a look in their forums

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a csproj with ProjectTypeGuids 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636034/how-to-open-a-csproj-with-projecttypeguids-349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ok the problem was too many changes, I unzipped the solution again and just changed
the first parameter in the `ProjectTypeGuids` to `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}`
so it looks like

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

and I can see the project hurray!

Comment: +1 -- too many other related posts. This one worked in VS 2008 for me with MVC2.

Comment: Do you know what 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21 (the second one) represents? I've worked out that that's the one I'm missing from my machine, but I have no idea what it is an what I should install to get this...

Comment: @Flater: Web Application (see here: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx

Comment: What is the Difference between 
{astrix astrix F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325 astrix astrix}
 and 
{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}

Comment: astrix astrix F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325 astrix astrix was actually attempt to show it in bold font

Comment: 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21 represented ASP.NET MVC 5. You can see a list of guids here: https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Answer (score 25):

Just had a similar problem when taking an older MVC / Azure WebRole project into VS 2012 with MVC4.  The trick was to edit the .CSPROJ like this:

```
10c11
<     <ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11
da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
---
>     <ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11
da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

i.e. change the first one from {F8... to {E3E3... (which is apparently MVC4).  This has to be done outside of Visual Studio, in a text editor, and then open the solution and "Reload" the project that gave an error - this will trigger VS to migrate it to VS 2012.

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to finally migrate my 2010 solution to 2012 which happened to on a different machine than it was originally created on. 2 years of looking finally resolved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en).

Comment: Same here, if it seems that when i installed MVC 3 through web pi, web pi started staying that MVC 2 is installed as well.  However, that was not the case. I end up installing MVC2 RTM and it solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue as @Roman, Web Platform Installer said I had it installed, however after installing from the exe all was fine.

Comment: Just had this same issue but with MVC 3 and 4. The MVC 3 installer also kept crashing due to a newer version of NuGet being installed, once I uninstalled that everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy way to solve this.

Probably some of the dependencies are missing, and it is really hard to find out which one.

Go to

http://www.asp.net/downloads

Download ASP.NET and WebTools for your version of Visual Studio

A web platform installer will come up, which will install all the required tools

This solved my problem

There is no need to go through the ProjectTypeGuids