# How do I open a csproj with ProjectTypeGuids 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2012 Professional. When I try to open a particular csproj I get an error message

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

It doesn't say what 'project type' the project is, nor what I need to install to be able to open it.

On inspecting the `.csproj` file, I see the lines

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

So **what do need I install** to be able to open this project? Please provide a link!

Comment: Guids are a pain for humans but a blessing for computers.  Just google the guid string and take the first hit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC project "not supported by this installation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531120/asp-net-mvc-project-not-supported-by-this-installation)

Comment: @HansPassant, that's now this page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found Visual Studio 2012 in the old 'add remove programs', then pressed 'change'. Fixed by installing 'Microsoft Web Developer Tools'

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me with VS2015

Answer (score 2):

There is a really easy way to solve this.

Probably some of the dependencies are missing, and it is really hard to find out which one.

Go to

http://www.asp.net/downloads

Download ASP.NET and WebTools for your version of Visual Studio

A web platform installer will come up, which will install all the required tools

This solved my problem

There is no need to go through the ProjectTypeGuids

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this ProjectType GUID lookup table [hosted on github](https://github.com/JamesW75/visual-studio-project-type-guid) (original [codeproject link here](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)), you can specifically understand what each of your GUIDs are:

```
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
```

| Description | GUID |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| ASP.NET MVC 5 | {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21} |
| ... | ... |
| C# | {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC} |

That is, when `<ProjectTypeGuids>` contains `{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}` you're looking at an **ASP.NET MVC 5 site written in C#**

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15639460/1175496) shows you *how to fix it/ open projects of these types*, but I was curious what *type of projects these are* before I try to fix.

Also the accepted answer is focused on fixing these projects in Visual Studio 2012 but one comment mentions about [not working with 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636034/how-do-i-open-a-csproj-with-projecttypeguids-349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f2#comment67632860_15639460).

For me (on Visual Studio 2017), I will try to fix it by installing

- "ASP.NET and web development" and
- ".NET desktop development"

(the second one might be optional) using Visual Studio Installer, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609885/asp-net-mvc-not-available-in-visual-studio-2017-pr?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-610103#newest-answer-comment), and shown in screenshot below (from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-setup-visual-studio-for-asp-net/))

[image: a screenshot of Visual Studio installer, installing two Workloads, "ASP.NET and web development" and ".NET desktop development"]