# Error trying to create a MVC Controller in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When i right click a folder and click "Add Controller" i get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This error also started to appear in Package Manager Console when i open the project.

```
New-Object : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\b\Desktop\Git\EyeglassShop\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.9\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1:163 char:27
+     $newProvider = New-Object <<<<  $powerShellScaffolderProviderType($mvcScaffoldingProvider)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

This is question is the exact same.

[Cannot add a MVC controller VS2012 gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148914/cannot-add-a-mvc-controller-vs2012-gives-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instanc)

The solution is to install PowerShell 3, However when i run the installer i get another error:

```
The update is not applicable to your computer.
```

Another thing worth mentioning, is that this error only accures in a specific project, it works fine if i create a new MVC project.

I't would be awesome if i could avoid moveing everything to a new project. Any suggestions?

**Update**

The error accours when trying to install MvcScaffolding from package manager console

```
PM> install-package MvcScaffolding
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding.Core'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework'.
Successfully installed 'T4Scaffolding.Core 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.8'.
Successfully installed 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.9'.
New-Object : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\b\Desktop\EyeglassShop\EyeglassShop\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.9\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1:163 char:27
+     $newProvider = New-Object <<<<  $powerShellScaffolderProviderType($mvcScaffoldingProvider)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Successfully added 'T4Scaffolding.Core 1.0.0' to EyeglassShop.
Successfully added 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.8' to EyeglassShop.
Successfully added 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.9' to EyeglassShop.
```

Comment: Make sure this happens to your specific project or on all project. Was your installation of vs 2012 is correct? This might be due to improper installation.

Answer (score 0):

I Needed to install SP 1 in order to install Powershell.. thourght i had it :p