# Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I create a new web project with Visual Studio, I only see the templates in the picture below:
[image: missing MVC template]

The MVC one is missing and so I can only create empty projects.

I tried with a repair of Visual Studio, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi

A couple of questions:

 - Under Help/About, does it show an entry for "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013" - the version should be 5.2.30624.0
 - Are the any files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\MVC?
 - What's the Target Framework in the File->New Project dialog set to?
 - When you repaired VS, did it create a log in your %temp% folder for MVC. The file should have a name similar to dd_vs_enterprise_DATETIME_NNN_aspnetwebfxtoolsvs14.log
 
Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Under About I have ASP.NET and WebTools 14.0.20711.0 and I'm missing the MVC folder. In the log say the removal was complete, but nothing related to a fresh new install. I will investigate that.

Comment: goto marketplace from visual studio, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesEloff.MicrosoftASPNETWebFrameworksandTools2015#review-details then you'll get all you need.

Comment: @zobidafly This didn't help for me.  The templates are still missing after running the installer.  Is there another step?

Comment: @Jonathon I got the templates in a two steps action, so first I have to select web application THEN the type of web application...tell me if you have the same behaviour...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just got the same issue after installing [Developer Tools
Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta7)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738). I tried to reinstall [ASP.NET Project Templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9402d38e-2a85-434e-8d6a-8fc075068a42) but it didn't help.

While looking into "Add / remove programs" -> "Visual 2015" -> "Modify"
, I found the **"Web developer tools"** unchecked. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15639460/533686) helps me to figure this.

After reinstalling this, everything reappears

[image]

Comment: The only thing different is that my option was already checked. I unchecked it, reopened the installer and found that the option was still checked. Anyway it worked.

Comment: Same experience as @Iridio.  Except that it still doesn't work.

Comment: To empty (directly above) and others who have experienced this issue I can only suggest you be persistent in repeating the steps as necessary. I just installed VS2015 With Updates - as of this date this includes the production release, i.e. Update 3 and ??, so everything _should_ work - but the template was missing. I repeated the steps rducom lists at least three times (I'm stubborn) and finally the template appeared.  This has been the most painful VS update since I started using it (VS2008)

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: This whole shooting match is broken. Terrible QC.

Comment: I tried that on VS15 proffessional but it refused , let me try for VS15 Enterprise

Comment: This is old, unrelated for the latest VS. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147724/984471

Answer (score 47):

Just click on the "web" in left side-bar and select "ASP.NET Web Application", click "ok" and you will see next dialog:

[image]

Now, you can choose type of web application what you want.

Comment: What if you do this and you see none of the ASP.NET 5 templates.

Comment: Thanks, some times we are too early to get results.

Comment: Important to note; you'll only see this if you clicked File > New > Project, not if you clicked File > New > Website when creating the project.

Answer (score 35):

I'm going to add my 2 cents in case someone finds himself in a position like mine. I too was looking for an MVC project type and could not see it. All I saw is a "Web Application Project". So I freaked out and rushed into trying all solutions listed on this page.

But.

**IT IS ACTUALLY THERE.**

[image]

Just go with the "Web application" project and it will give you the MVC option on the next step.

Comment: Should be the answer.

Comment: Its the answer and actually my savior..I am fooled around before..thanks

Comment: My problem was that we're working on Framework 4.0, which does not support MVC. Moving to framework 4.5.2 fixed this.

Answer (score 11):

Visual studio 2015 does not show MVC project template if you select .Net 4.0 or below. Select .Net 4.5 or above, and you will be able to see MVC project.

This is what showed when you select .NET Framework 4:

[image]

and this when you select .NET Framework 4.5:

[image]

However, make sure you have installed web developers tools. To do so, go to  Add / remove programs -> Visual 2015 -> Modify -->  Web developer tools : Check and proceed with the installation.

Comment: There is no MVC in either of your screenshots.

Comment: @Timwi, The choice of MVC comes after user clicks the OK Button

Comment: You should have added the MVC screenshot since that's the question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the accepted answer works anymore. According to Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879354.aspx), [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/), [and here](http://www.asp.net/core), [asp.net-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) has been re-branded to `ASP.Net Core`. It looks like they've taken down the [asp.net-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) templates from the general ASP.Net Web Application project type. But now there's a new project type of ASP.Net Core Web Application. [image]I don't see an MVC template for this project type, but I don't think the Core framework has been completely released yet.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the MVC template not appearing in VS2015.

I checked Web Developer Tools when originally installing. It was still checked when trying to Modify the install. I tried unchecking and updating the install but next time I went back to Modify, it was still checked. And still no MVC template.

I got it working by uninstalling: `Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015` via the `Programs and Features` windows and re-installing. [Here's the link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f8a7e60-2e6b-4220-b334-26d1e60ec54c) for those who don't have it.

Comment: Perhaps this is the easiest fix on this page.  I checked Programs and Features and couldn't see Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015.  Followed the link, downloaded it and installed it, everything was fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that happened when uninstalling AspNet 5 RC1 Update 1 to update it for .Net Core 1.0 RC2. so I installed Visual Studio 2015 update 2, selected Microsoft Web Developer tools and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I saw none of the MVC templates (except the bottom two), after installing Update 3 which installed all the Core stuff.

[image: missing mvc]

**Solution**

I downloaded most recent core preview...

[image: corepreview]

It prompted me for "repair" and after it was done, bringing up VS indicated it was "Installing Templates" and they appeared!

**Warning**

Update 3 is a game changer in that the "preferred" way of doing things is to use dotnetcore.  For example a console application now uses the new file stucture, other projects such as a Test Project still use the same folder structure as before.  But MVC has changed.  I'm not even sure what other "Web Developer Tools" work with dotnetcore right now.

Answer (score 1):

write this in nuget console `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3`

Comment: This needs some clarification as to what it does and how it fixes the issue or explain why it worked for you.

Comment: It will install the mvc 5 template for you using nugget.. You could have asked me before downvoting

Comment: actually, I did not downvote. The person that did forgot to give a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 (Community update 3, in my scenario) uses a default template for the MVC project. You don't have to select it.

I found this tutorial and I think it answers the question:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html

check out the old versions of this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Times have changed. Including .NET

Answer (score 0):

Other answer looks old.

For Visual Studio 2017, screen shots are below

---

[image: New project]

---

[image: ASP.NET web Application]

---

[image: MVC option]

---

[image: MVC in solution explorer]

---