# Installation errors in repair of Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows 10

Tags: installation, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

While trying to fix [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015) I ran "repair" on my copy of VS 2015 on Win10.  But when the repair completed I had the following errors:

```
Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Service : Package failed.
Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21) : The following package(s) were not downloaded: addon-google_apis-google-19 addon-google_apis_x86-google-19 android-19 android-21 android-22 build-tools-19.1.0 build-tools-21.1.2 build-tools-22.0.1 extra-android-m2repository extra-android-support platform-tools sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19 sys-img-x86-android-19 . Please check your internet connection and try again.
Android SDK Setup (API Level 22) : The following package(s) were not downloaded: addon-google_apis-google-19 addon-google_apis_x86-google-19 android-19 android-21 android-22 build-tools-19.1.0 build-tools-21.1.2 build-tools-22.0.1 extra-android-m2repository extra-android-support platform-tools sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19 sys-img-x86-android-19 . Please check your internet connection and try again.
GitHub Extension for Visual Studio : A VSIX extension with a matching Identifier is already installed to this product.
```

Any ideas for how to fix it?  Please don't say reinstall, it takes ages to do that and based on previous experience with VS installs, I'll probably have the same errors.

I ran repair *again* on VS 2015 which forced me to install the latest update.  Now the error is just:

```
Android SDK Setup (API Level 23) : The following package(s) were not downloaded: build-tools-23.0.1 android-23 . Please check your internet connection and try again.
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: any luck  on this?  mine is stuck with `The following package(s) were not downloaded: addon-google_apis_x86-google-19`

Comment: @SanuelJackson sorry I ended up restarting the PC and the install multiple times and then it just worked.  No idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Java SE was outdated, so i needed to install Java SE 1.8 version.