# Visual Studio 2015 versions - Parallell installations

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Can installing different 2015 versions in parallell or at different times cause problems?

Also, to what extent are the installations shared (Items not duplicated)?

Do the open source versions have different binaries?

(Have had problems before - therefore this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have all of the VS 2015 Express (Web, Desktop, Windows) and one of VS 2015 Community/Professional/Enterprise on the same OS installation. The installation obviously share various SDK, .NET Frameworks compiler and tools, but the VS-shell is different. Doesn't mean much except it's possible to have one of your Express stopped working while the Community run fine, and vice versa.

There is no open source versions of VS currently, I assume you mean the gratis but proprietary Community? Aside from the specific features (mostly while coding/debugging) exclusively available on Professional or Enterprise, all VS 2015 editions (Express if the project type is supported) including Community will generate identical binaries since they're calling the same compiler anyway.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414480/can-visual-studio-community-2015-be-easily-updated-to-visual-studio-professional) suggests uninstallation before moving between Community, Professional and Enterprise.

EDIT :
After your clarification, VS Code is a self-contained app that happen to have VS branding. The only shared requirements is .NET Framework, but otherwise it should have no interference risk.

Comment: "There is no open source versions of VS currently, I assume you mean the gratis but proprietary Community" -  "Visual Studio Code" is open source.

Comment: Eh, VS Code is so far different from VS. It's just a Node.js-powered code editor slapped with VS brand. It doesn't even have a compiler. No shared binaries with real VS (both call the .NET Framework, but that's it). So zero risk of interference with the real VS,