# Does Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition have MVC templates?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

When I try to create an ASP.NET 5 project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition I don't see the MVC templates:
[image]

I've tried the solutions from "[Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)" but no joy.

Does Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition have MVC templates?

Comment: I suspect the MVC project mentioned at the top under 4.5.2 is actually using MVC 5. The MVC version and ASP.NET version and the .NET Frameworkversion haven't been in sync for a while now.

Comment: Plus, when using the ASP.NET 5 templates, you cna create a Web Application and then check the [x] MVC checkbox under the big selection box to enable MVC.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing!  How would I quickly check to see if the MVC 4.5.2 is in fact MVC5?

Comment: Check the System.Web.MVC version I suspect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer as I moved on was embarrassingly simple.  There's no option for MVC templates under ASP.NET 5 because choosing Web Application gives you MVC templates.

Answer (score 4):

Asp.net 4.5.2 uses MVC 5 if you select the MVC template in the 4.5.2 section. You can check this by looking at the web.config after you have created the project and the version number of MVC will be there.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If you select ASP.NET 5 you will get MVC 6 which is a very different animal.