# Visual Studio 2015 MVC Project Templates missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

As suggested in answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015) question, I tried modifying the program but **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** is already checked and installed.

[image]

I've used to choose **Basic MVC project template** when I was in Visual studio 2013.

[image]

But now in visual Studio 2015 I didn't find any of those options, It now seems like this

[image]

It directly creates **Internet Application** as in template based on previous versions of VS after choosing **MVC** option as shown in image and I don't want that.

Is there any idea to get those templates in visual studio 2015 ? Actually I'm new in c#, web development and visual studio. Any suggestions, or even comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your last screenshot shows that you have selected a template for an MVC project.  What's the problem?

Comment: These are what comes with Visual studio 2015 and if you want to use MVC you just select MVC and create a new project. You should find all the stuff you need in there

Comment: Also, when I look at VS 2013 I see basically the same as for 2015, which suggests to me that your second screenshot shows VS 2013 without the latest Update.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yah I am selecting it, But it creates project directly as **internet application**. It won't give option to select the template.

Comment: @jamiedanq All I need is only the Basic template which contains only folder of controller view and other extras. But it creates whole internet application and I don't want that.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna if you don't want all the extras why not create an empty MVC application and then you add the few bits you want yourself

Comment: @ShreeKrishna can you show what you call a basic template contains

Comment: @jamiedanq Are you sure all the configurations will be ok in empty project. and only controller and view folders are missing ? And after creating those folder will it be exactly as basic template ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna it will be ok. it still contains the controller and view folders if thats what you are worried about

Comment: @jamiedanq No bro I tried, But there is nothing rather than script folder. Even no appstart and other rest. It's completely empty.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna after you select `Empty`, at the **Add folders and core references for** section Select `MVC`

Comment: @jamiedanq Thanks I tried it. Add it as answer with proper formatting and descriptions as well, I will accept that. And I appreciate your precious time you've given on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 your **Basic MVC project template** in Visual studio 2013 is similar to creating an Empty project and adding `MVC` as a **core reference**

You can get it done by following the below when you get to this pop up

[image]

Hope this helped