# Visual Studio: Convert 'Empty ASP.NET' template into MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a fast and easy way to convert an existing 'Empty ASP.NET' template into another one, i.e. MVC or SinglePage Application, or vice versa?

Comment: `Empty ASP.NET`? I think you should create new project with type MVC or SinglePage Application,... Because your project is empty.

Comment: The project itself is not empty, it was created from an 'Empty ASP.NET' template.

Comment: Add the required `MVC` references you need to the `EMPTY` project or better still look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736710/visual-studio-2015-mvc-project-templates-missing/36740245#36740245

Answer (score 2):

To convert to MVC project. 
First, you need install Package `Microsoft ASP.NET MVC` includes all the resources that you need to use MVC such as references, web.config changes, etc… .
After install success. You should create folder necessary like Models, Controller, Views,.... like MVC project.

In ASP MVC using Razor views instead of .aspx. Using this tools to convert code quick.

https://razorconverter.codeplex.com/

After all, you should read [this article in the blog](https://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/9-steps-to-switch-from-asp-net-web-forms-to-mvc/) to convert.

Not anyway quick or one-click to convert ASP to ASP MVC. You must change code and concept of MVC.