# Unable to find MVC template in Visual Studio2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

[Screenshot from Visual Studio2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXVBC.png)

File -> New Project ->Web-> ASP .Net Web Application

I am using VisualStudio 2015 Community version, before I was able see option MVC on this page, but I am confused what should have went wrong.
I tried creating project using WebApplication option available, this created a template which mostly looks like MVC, few new folders like migration and services.
It will be great if someone can help me through this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Yes did check that but, It gives solution for who install Visual Studio recently, they can uninstall and install it back without losing any files, but I am using it from long and also used MVC template too, but don't know it stopped showing up now.

Comment: If you are trying to create an ASP.NET 5 MVC app, you have the correct template on the bottom there. Web Application will give you a small demo application. The empty application will give you the empty project where you have to just create the MVC folders yourself.

Comment: Thanks Reza and Alex

Comment: Already answered here <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015</a>

Comment: Already answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015