# Class Library project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I used the Class Library project rather frequently whilst using VS 2013. I am now on VS 2015 (yep, slow to migrate) and I don't see a Class Library project available. Has its moniker changed? Is there an equivalent project type?

Can I just add a class instead now?

Comment: I have visual c# selected from add new project. Under web there are only asp.net applications. I see a dot net core class library but I don't want that, I want the prior class library type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few options here:

1) Use class library project from Windows subsection:

[image]

2) Search for a template online. There is a link that reads: Click here to go online and find templates (at the bottom of the dialog shown in the printscreen).

There you can search for a class library in the Web section:

[image]

3) Modify VS installation and check Microsoft Web Developer Tool. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720390/3330348).

4) Try reinstalling [ASP.NET templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9402d38e-2a85-434e-8d6a-8fc075068a42).