# No MVC template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have  missing MVC template in Visual studio 2015. I followed every answer posted in this topic in stackoverflow. I tried modifying and installing again and i checked web developer section too. But still MVC template is not in web section.

Comment: What do you have on the main screen, when you select the Web Template?

Comment: Empty , Web Forms , Azure Api , Azure mobile Service and Get Asp.net RC5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have forgotten to install `Web Developer tools` on the initial installation.

[image]

After reinstalling this, everything reappears

Reference: [Check this Solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Check the comments on the solution, too.
- The only thing different is that my option was already checked. I unchecked it, reopened the installer and found that the option was still checked. Anyway it worked. @Jason