# How to create new MVC5 project on VS 2015 enterprise edition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

**1. This picture show version of VS2015**
[image]

**2. List of Install product**

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-90150-00969-AA240

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015   00322-90150-00969-AA240

Visual Basic 2015   00322-90150-00969-AA240

Visual C# 2015   00322-90150-00969-AA240

Visual C++ 2015   00322-90150-00969-AA240

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.18.00214.2

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.21111.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   14.0.30222.0

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.6000.1

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.6000.1

Common Azure Tools   1.8

JavaScript Language Service   2.0

JavaScript Project System   2.0

Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.21111.0

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.2.6000.1

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.2.6000.1

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.2.6000.1

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9

NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2

SQL Server Analysis Services   13.0.1701.8

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61021.0

SQL Server Integration Services

SQL Server Reporting Services   13.0.1701.8

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0

TypeScript   1.8.36.0

**3. I want to create new MVC project then I click *"New Project"* and i select *Visual C# Web* in menu on left panel shown as picture below.**[image]

3.1 I click new project and select **ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework)** and click OK then it's show no MVC. Look at the picture below.[image]

3.2 I change from **ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework)** to **ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Core)** it same issue no MVC. Look at the picture below.[image]

3.3 I change to **ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Framework)** it same issue no MVC.[image]

How to create new MVC5 project on VS 2015 enterprise edition.?
How to find MVC template.?

"Sorry for bad english skill"

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32720390/4868839)

Comment: Select `Web Application` in the last selection section. MVC is default for dotnet core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have missed to check "Microsoft Web Developer Tools(see the image below)" while installing VS2015. Modify your VS2015 and this time check this option to install so the MVC options should appear again.

After installing Microsoft Web Developer Tools; Select "ASP.NET Web Application" and then select "MVC" to create your MVC project. After creating it, go to reference folder, look for System.Web.MVC, right-click on it, select Properties and look at the Version property. It should be something like "5.x.x" and targetFramework ="net452".

[image]

For more details please [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015) Hope it helps.