# MVC template missing in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

After Finishing VS2015 setup I can't find MVC template. then I Modified it and selected  Microsoft Developer tools and the issue still not fixed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)