# MVC template missing for .NET framework 4 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

Noob here! I'm trying to create a Web Application using .NET 4 framework with MVC template in Visual Studio PRO 2019, as our server still uses .NET 4.

Steps I used to create project : [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87tyb.png) --> [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZfSB.png) --> [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLF9T.png)

The MVC templates are not populated and the Text boxes are disabled for .NET 4 (See Step 3), but MVC template appears for .NET Framework 4.5 and above though, check [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zeCj.png), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy0Ps.png)

That's when I came across the [Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ext4p.png) in the post [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015), My question is, **Is it possible to even create MVC template using .NET framework 4 in Visual studio 2019 ?**

I'd appreciate any leads here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only ASP.NET MVC 5.x is supported in VS2017 and above,

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-aspnet-mvc4-in-vs2017/284556

So you won't be able to target .NET Framework 4.0, but 4.5 and above, as that's the dependency of ASP.NET MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, you can see the following link about the similar question [Asp.Net Mvc Template](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/aspnet-mvc-template-missing/784415) missing in the Developer Community.

The last reply by Phil Henning [MSFT] says that it will occur the problem when you select .NET Framework 4 or earlier.

If you still want to solve the problem, you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).

Answer (score 0):

Check .Net 4.x framework is installed in VisualStudio Installer.