# Can open MVC4 solution in VS2010, but not in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Looked through some similar questions, could not find one that fits my case.

I have a solution that I created some time ago in VS 2010 (maybe originally in MVC2), and eventually upgraded to MVC4.
The solution works properly when opened with VS 2010, builds and runs - everything as expected.

To confirm that I use MVC4, I checked the properties of my System.Web.Mvc.dll. It appears to be 4.0.0.0

[image]

From this I assume that I have MVC4 successfully installed on the machine.

However, when I try to open the solution with VS 2012 I get the following infamous error

[image]

Full text:

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio does not have the following
>   project types installed or does not support them. You can still open
>   these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were
>   originally created.
>      - Recipes, "C:\ ... Copy\Recipes\Recipes.csproj"

I can also create a new MVC4 project using VS 2012, so I'm assuming I don't lack any tools VS 2012 needs.

What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an entry in the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element of the .csproj file that VS2012 doesn't recognize. I have a vague recollection there was some tooling identifier change but I can't recall specifically.

My suggestion would be to create a new project from scratch and then compare the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` elements in each .csproj file to try to figure out which one from the VS2010 project it doesn't like in VS2012. It's likely going to require some trial-and-error tweaking of the list so make a backup of the file first so you don't get yourself into a situation where you can't open it at all.

If you don't want to take that approach another option would be to create a new empty project and then import the individual files from the old project into the new, but that could obviously be quite time-consuming if it's a large project.

Comment: Spot on. Had to change guid from 
F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325
to 
E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47. 
BTW, searching by guid I found the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531120/asp-net-mvc-project-not-supported-by-this-installation and looks like the highest upvoted answer suggests the wrong guid rename, but the accepted answer is correct. For my case, at least - as for that other question, the author does not clearly state his MVC and VS versions ...